# excel ole db connection string error, "initialization of the data source failed"

Tags: excel, import, connection, oledb, jet

I am attempting to import data from an access database using the following connection string:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Password="";User ID=Admin;Data Source="C:\Temp\Dextech PM.mdb";Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="";Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False"
```

When I attempt to make the connection, it fails with the following error:

> initialization of the data source failed
>
> Check the database server or contact your database administrator. Make sure the external database is available, and then try the operation again. If you see this message again, create a new datasource to connect tot he database.

The connection will not connect, so I can't import data.

Comment: You can't have `"` characters inside your connection string unless you escape them by doubling them up - e.g. `Data Source=""C:\Temp\Dextech PM.mdb""` The `Password=""` part is a likely suspect here and should be replaced by `Password=""""`

Comment: ...or replaced by `Password=;User ID=Admin;`